# Does Struts 1.0 support Java 7

Tags: java, struts

Hi we are currently using Struts 1.0, JAVA 6 and J boss 7

so we tried to migrating J boss to newer version but before that we need to make sure,

Struts 1.0 support JAVA 7

Comment: Have you tried running it on Java 7? What happened?

Comment: Struts is a framework that runs on Java. There is a base version where a framework can run, and *it's supposed to* be able to run on future Java implementations. In order to verify if Java 7 supports struts (not vice versa), just start your app using JRE 7 and get the results.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : if switching to Java 7 causes any problems, then these problems will probably be subtle and hard to find. So this is an entirely valid question to ask.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak it would be too broad in that case, then. And you won't know unless you make the test and find this case. Also, Struts 1.0 doesn't receive any support, which makes this question a *the force and the luck be with you* question type.

Comment: WE tried running application with Java 7, Works fine. we are going to update J boss new version in local test it and apply in Higher environment.. Thanks for all the Comments

Comment: Most likely it does, yes. That said... you *really* shouldn't be using Struts 1.0, for a variety of reasons.